# VBA code returning Object Required error, unsure of what is causing it

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ms-office, com-automation

Having some issues with my code, I've removed the URL since it requires specific access. I have confirmed the ID is correct and copy/pasted rather than manual typing. My code does open up IE, opens the correct URL, but does not paste "test" into the description box. What have I done wrong? I've bolded the line that returns the error.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    Url = "website"

    With IE
        .navigate Url
        .Visible = True
        'Waiting till page loads
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
            Debug.Print "Waiting on IE" & Time
        Loop

    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:08"))
    
    **IE.document.getElementById("new_call.description").Value = "test"**
End Sub
```

Comment: Likely `getElementById("new_call.description")` is not making a match, so you get "object required" when you try to set its value.

Comment: I believe you're correct Tim since I just tested this code but changed it to bing search box with that the bing search box ID and it worked flawlessly but I don't get it since the ID is exactly what I'm typing, my HTML definitely sucks here is the imgur of the element I'm trying to match: https://imgur.com/a/ezNl6ds

Do you happen to have any thoughts?

Comment: id of the hilited section is "new_call.short_description" not "new_call.description" as you have in your posted code?

Comment: ah, sorry, I misclicked on the short description field. There is also a description field. Neither IDs work. Wonder if its something regarding security on this website since it is Ticketing software.

Comment: Are you sure that element isn't in a frame/iframe?  That would be a different `document` object from `IE.document`...

Comment: Will check in a few, currently in a meeting. Out of curiosity, are you a program manager? I just realized my program manager is also a Tim Williams that I've never met and it would be icing on the cake if that happened to be you.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a coincidence?  Not me though 

Comment: Hey Tim, doesn't look to be an iframe/frame. From what it looks like it is HTML[data-doctype=true] .form-group .form-field. So it's definitely a form. At the beginning of the html in inspect, it's labeled as a textarea and class = "form-control"

on the input side, the type = "hidden" I'm wondering if this hidden is causing it to not be seen by outside programs like excel? Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the HTML for the actual field you want?  Are you able to work with the other fields?  If it's a `textarea` you want `.innerText` not `.Value`

Comment: https://postimg.cc/rD8t8Fjq here is the field I want, for some reason it's not wrapping. Yay IE.

Also .innerText returned the same error.

Comment: I don't see anything there which would explain your problem...

Comment: Yea, I'm also completely out of ideas as well. It works in other websites but not this one. I'm wondering if this website is just secure and won't allow auto-filling of any sort, but I've never encountered that before so I'm just going to go with that and call it a bust. If you can think of anything/need more info, let me know.

Comment: I've been testing this for a bit, and the only instance this happens for me is if its inside an iframe. An iframe doesnt have to call another website/file, you can create an iframe tag and fill it with .innerHtml and will work as an iframe. Can you do a search for iframe and check if this is inside one?

Comment: Hey Ricardo, I did do an iframe search and it does not look like this is within an iframe at all. Also used: element.new_call.short_description as id name too and it didn't work. Please refer to the following screenshot as I was able to do way more info on this one: https://postimg.cc/Yh5jmMQm